# Какую версию PHP выбрать для сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, сервер

На первый взгляд ответ простой - последнюю.))) Я тоже так считаю, но когда я скачивал PHP 5.3 (5.3.8) VC9 для Windows, то увидел следующую информацию:

**Какую версию выбрать?

-Если вы используете PHP с Apache 1 или Apache2 от apache.org вам нужно использовать VC6 версий PHP

-Если вы используете PHP с IIS вы должны использовать VC9 версий PHP

-VC6 Версии составляются с наследием Visual Studio 6 компилятор

-VC9 Версии составляются с Visual Studio 2008 компилятор и есть улучшения в производительности и стабильности. VC9 версии требутся установить Microsoft 2008 C + + Runtime (x86) или Microsoft 2008 C + + Runtime (x64)

-Не использовать VC9 версию с apache.org файлами.

-VC9 версии Apache могут быть выбраны в Apache Lounge. Мы используем их для создания бинарных файлов Apache видами SAPI.**

На моем хостинге сейчас подключен сервер **Apache 1.3.* [s56, Windows 2008 R2], aux3**

Есть вариант перевести на **Linux 2.6 с модулями Apache 1.3.*, Fast CGI, CGI**

или

Windows Server 2008 R2 с модулями IIS 6.0 или IIS 7.0

Comment: Это понятно, что лучше последнюю. Но как я понял, последняя версия не будет работать с сервером, на котором расположен мой сайт (Apache 1.3.* [s56, Windows 2008 R2], aux3). Под моим сервером будет работать версия PHP 5.2 (5.2.17). Или все таки нет разницы?

Comment: Думаю, что нет разницы какой у вас апач, php будет работать нормально ) так что ставьте последний, а вообще V_Tjuryakin правильно говорит, почитайте про Ваш релиз, раз уж так встал вопрос, може там ничего критичного и не фиксилось в следующих версиях, и имеет смысл остаться на 5.2, раз там все работает )
а, и да, если есть вариант перейти на линукс - переходите. Сервер - это линукс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы предпочел php 5.3.8, причем не в связке с apache а с nginx через fcgi.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень вразумительный и точный ответ...))) Осталось узнать почему? Но это я уже из инета буду выяснять. По крайней мере есть откуда плясать и на что обращать внимание...)))

Comment: 5.3.8 из-за безопасности - большинство известных дыр залатано, о новых еще не известно.

nginx по шустрее апача, и из своего опыта знаю что он получше апача справляется с php. Хотя есть и некоторые минусы.

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно последнюю. По-Вашему, для чего выпускают новые версии? Да, и для того, чтобы внести новые возможности, но главнейшая причина, все-таки, устранение уязвимостей, которые в старых версиях уже известны, и это проблема не только open source языков, а и любого опен сорс ПО: все всё о нем знают :)

Comment: Спасибо всем за хорошие ответы...)))
Я в программировании не новичок, но что касается PHP  и серверов - полный ноль... Очень давно я изучил html, css и javascript. Стал изучать Java, считая, что это будущее вебдизайна (но ошибся). Теперь приходится переучиваться, и что бы не допустить ошибок прошлого - хотелось уточнить у специалистов по поводу языка.
Что касается серверов. Я знаю, что все сервера работают под Unix. Поэтому вопрос. На какой модуль перейти? Apache 1.3.*, Fast CGI, CGI.

Comment: Не все, к сожалению, есть сервера, работающие под windows.

Comment: Я может не так выразился...))) Сервер должен работать под *nix. А все остальное ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

На вашем бы месте, я изначально почитал бы про релизы, какие недочёты есть или исправлены.
И вообще бы я на вашем месте выбрал только [*unix](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) систему.

Comment: Сказать честно, мне пока рано читать релизы. Раз исправили, значить надо...))) Как Вы считаете какой модуль выбрать? Сайт у меня пока написан на html, css. Планирую перейти на PHP, но разумеется процентов 70-80 останется html. Я еще не готов так сразу и быстро освоить PHP.

Comment: Вы из своего списка показали только один сервер *unix. Так-что на него ;)

Comment: эм) звездочку перед unix заметили?:)

Answer (score 0):

Последнюю стабильную - 5.3.8